# Docker WSL on Windows 11 - Ubuntu user

Tags: ubuntu, password, windows-subsystem-for-linux

According [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment#set-up-your-linux-username-and-password) for installing docker on Windows I have installed WSL with its Ubuntu dist. Next step should be set up user and password for Ubutnu. So according documentation I open Ubuntu from start menu and it shows console window with text: Press any key to continue. But as I do it it disapears and I can not set user. Picture shows the console window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your system is missing some Windows feature. How did you set up WSL? Also, which OS and build are you running?

You can find the documentation for installing WSL here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

Comment: The problem was I did not restart system. Now it was ok user and pass is set up. Thanks.